# dragging "Div" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

How can we make a div movable from here to there. I tried using JQuery Drag, Drop & sortable kind of things but my requirements is not fulfilling.

I have a plenty of DIVs on the page and  i need to drag & drop a DIV_1 onto DIV_2,then DIV_2 should be adjust/set in place of DIV_1. Such drag n drop kind of things works when i have very few DIV but it doesn't work when i have many DIVs inside differnt ROW(div) & COLOUMN(div).

Does anybody tell me?

Comment: So what have you tried and what is currently not working?

Comment: Would you be good enough to give us an URL, please, so we can see the problem for ourselves? Thanks.

Comment: It works when i have DIVs in same ROW or Column, but i got stuck when a page consist many nested ROW & COLUMN (as a div) which consists many DIV(draggable element) inside. I get confuse to handle the nested draggable DIV when  it should drag/drop out of it's parent div.

Comment: Hi Wilson, I have uploaded the page, please take a look http://mystuff.comze.com/calc.html                              The problem is button button (7,8,9,C) is in same row and can be drag & drop in same row while i want to drag and drop in other row/column too. like Button (7) over Button(4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to use jQuery Draggable & Droppable ... programming it yourself might be a bigger pill than you'd want to swallow.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/